# How can (if at all) the below matrix be factorized?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we have the matrix
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
ac &ad\\
be & bf
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Is there anyway to factor out $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write this as $$\left[\matrix{a & 0\cr 0 & b\cr}\right] \left[\matrix{c & d\cr e & f\cr}\right]$$
if that's what you mean.